# How do I locally reference files in my python project?

Tags: python, github

I'm trying to create an exe "game" (more of a proof-of-concept), but when I do the image files don't show up. :

```
parentDirectory = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), os.pardir))
photo = tk.PhotoImage(file = os.path.join(parentDirectory, 'okokokokok1.1','imgs', 'spooky.PNG'),width=320,height=240)
```

i honestly don't understand whats wrong someone pls help thx ;3

Comment: `os.getcwd()` is not necessarily the same directory where the currently-executing python module is located.  Try printing it.

Comment: instead of `os.getcwd()` you should use `os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))` because `getcwd` gives `Current Working Directory` which doesn't have to be `Directory with Script`

Comment: you may have common problem with `BUG` in `PhotoImage` which removes image from memory when you assign `PhotoImage` to local variable. It may need to assign to global variable or to other class - ie. to label which will display image `label.photo = tk.PhotoImage(...)`. See `Note` at the end of page https://web.archive.org/web/20201112023229/http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/photoimage.htm This problem was so many times on Stackoverflow that you should find solution on SO if you would try to search at least `PhotoImage problem`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@furas solved my query, thank you.
their comment:

> instead of `os.getcwd()` you should use `os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))` because `getcwd` gives `Current Working Directory` which doesn't have to be `Directory with Script`